# Atomic INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS (Postgres 9.6.3)

Tags: postgresql

The following statement suffers a race condition which I can reliably demonstrate by executing it concurrent in very quick succession.  Is there a way to remove this race condition from the below of do I need to take a different approach altogether?

```
INSERT INTO scheduled_event_log ("key") 
SELECT 'test' 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
        SELECT AGE(now() at time zone 'utc', timestamp_utc) 
        FROM scheduled_event_log 
        WHERE "key" = 'test' 
        AND age(now() at time zone 'utc', timestamp_utc) < '6s' FOR UPDATE);
```

Table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE scheduled_event_log (
  "key" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  "timestamp_utc" timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

Comment: It is atomic, but it is subject to a race condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does adding FOR UPDATE to the inner SELECT fix that? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

Comment: You only insert when the `SELECT` has found (and hence locked) zero records, so the `FOR UPDATE` isn't going to help. I think you'll need to either come up with some [advisory locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) scheme, or get all writers to run in a [serialisable transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) (possibly more trouble than it's worth...).

Comment: @NickBarnes of course! thanks.  So in my use case to lock the entire table would be fine so I knocked up the following function..however, there is still a race condition :/ https://gist.github.com/myles-mcdonnell/ca176a8dd1c2bda2d0754540819fa66c

Comment: @Myles: Doesn't make much sense to me... The `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock should essentially make the whole thing single-threaded, which doesn't leave much room for concurrency issues. Could you provide a self-contained example, i.e. including the table definitions, and scripts to create/detect the race condition?