# Postgres atomic insert at interval

Tags: postgresql

Given the following table I need to be able to run multiple concurrent processes that try to insert new rows every *n* seconds. Only one should should succeed per *n* seconds:

```
CREATE TABLE scheduled_event_log (
  "key" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  "timestamp_utc" timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

For example, over a 10 second period 20 concurrent insert statements will be executed.  Only one of them should succeed.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: How is this different then your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48073958/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's more open ended.  The other question is focused on why a particular approach fails whereas this simply spells out the requirement and asks for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than locking the table, perhaps you could add another field to the table to represent the seconds interval and add a unique key to that field (to fail the duplicate insert attempts). The field could be set to a default value during insertion along these lines:

```
trunc(extract('epoch' from now())::numeric, -1)
```

Or, rather than adding another field, perhaps a unique function based index based on `timestamp_utc` and a formula like above would make sense. `trunc(numeric, -1)` will truncate the last digit from the seconds leaving 10s grouping intervals.

Example:

```
SELECT key, ts, trunc(extract('epoch' from ts)::numeric, -1)
  FROM (VALUES (1, '2017-01-01 08:30:01'::timestamp)
              ,(2, '2017-01-01 08:30:05'::timestamp)
              ,(3, '2017-01-01 08:30:09'::timestamp)
              ,(4, '2017-01-01 08:30:10'::timestamp)
              ,(5, '2017-01-01 08:30:15'::timestamp)
              ,(6, '2017-01-01 08:30:20'::timestamp)
       ) AS t (key, ts);
```

Result:

```
| key |                   ts |      trunc |
|-----|----------------------|------------|
|   1 | 2017-01-01T08:30:01Z | 1483259400 |
|   2 | 2017-01-01T08:30:05Z | 1483259400 |
|   3 | 2017-01-01T08:30:09Z | 1483259400 |
|   4 | 2017-01-01T08:30:10Z | 1483259410 |
|   5 | 2017-01-01T08:30:15Z | 1483259410 |
|   6 | 2017-01-01T08:30:20Z | 1483259420 |
```

Comment: Nice approach. Doesn't work for my use case unfortunately as I'm interested in the time elapsed since the last entry rather than interval buckets.  e.g. in this example if the last entry where 2017-01-01T08:30:09Z and I try to insert 2017-01-01T08:30:10Z it will succeed even though they are only one second apart whereas my requirement is never to have two rows closer than an arbitrary interval asspecified by the client.